# Can I write Latex in Notes?

Tags: latex, drawing

I am using my iPad (with pencil) and my MacBook to write a document. I type using my Mac and draw some drawings in between texts. I want to add some Latex formulas, however, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Is it possible to write Latex in notes or more generally, is there any software that lets me type (in macOS), draw (on iPad), and use Latex formulas **simultaneously**?

Comment: You could try Notion app. It is a good note-taker that has a lot of features including support for Katex which is like Latex but slightly different for more obscure symbols.

Comment: Notability has a really good freehand to formula feature, but you cant type LaTeX on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the preinstalled Pages application on MacOS to write Latex formulas, using the Insert Equation function.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how the user can actually enter/use Latex formulas in a Pages document. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.

Answer (score 1):

I use [LaTeXiT](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php) and it does the job for small formulas in between text. I do try to write directly in text (with CMU font) whenever possible to avoid a "floating" object in the text.

Comment: How does this work in combination with drawing on an iPad, in the same document?

Comment: It works like any other object you add to your document. Works on macBook, I'm not sure about an iPad version,

Comment: The OP specifically asks for being able to **simultaneously** edit a document on both devices.

Comment: The OP asked (before the last edit), to " type (on mac), draw (on iPad), and use Latex formulas (on mac)". The answer fits this aim. However, once the question was edited, this answer fits no more.